# Possible inequality containing hyperbolic functions

Tags: calculus, hyperbolic-functions

I've got this inequality, and don't know how to attack it. I assumed the converse and saw the left side can't be equal to $\pi/2$. But I feel there is something good I can't see. Any help? Thanks.

$$\text{arccosh}(a/x)+\text{arcsinh}(x/a)>\pi/2, ~~~(0<x<\pi/2,a\geq 3)$$

[image]

Comment: Do you really mean "arccos" without "h" and "arcsin" with "h" or is this maybe a typing error?

Comment: @Martin: Oh sorry. Yes that's right. I edited it accordingly.

Comment: "Quo usque tandem abutere, Catilina, patientia nostra?" (Ciceron).

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\text{arccosh}(a/x)+\text{arcsinh}(x/a)$$
$$f{\space'}(x)=\frac{-a}{x\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}\lt0$$ Hence the function $f$ is decreasing in the given interval $0<x<\dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

Take now $f\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)\approx2.852688\gt\dfrac{\pi}{2}\approx1.570779$.

Consequently, because of $f$ is decreasing, $$f(x)\gt\dfrac{\pi}{2}\text{ in the interval}\space 0\lt x\lt \dfrac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: Doesn't $f(\frac{\pi}{2})$ depend on the value of a?